# git: Show message of last commit in commit template

Tags: git

`git commit` opens the text editor and displays some information about the changes to be committed:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#

#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
```

I would like to extend this template to display

- the first line of the `N` last commit messages and/or
- the complete message of the last commit

of the current branch. How can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will use git `hooks`.

- In your project root directory navigate to `.git/hooks/`
- Now create the file `prepare-commit-msg`
- Add the following bit of code:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
ORIG_MSG_FILE="$1"  # Grab the current template
TEMP=`mktemp /tmp/git-msg-XXXXX` # Create a temp file
trap "rm -f $TEMP" exit # Remove temp file on exit

MSG=`git log -1 --pretty=%s` # Grab the first line of the last commit message

(printf "\n\n# Last Commit: %s \n\n" "$MSG"; cat "$ORIG_MSG_FILE") > "$TEMP"  # print all to temp file
cat "$TEMP" > "$ORIG_MSG_FILE" # Move temp file to commit message
```

- `chmod +x prepare-commit_message`

Idea borrowed from [Enhancing git commit messages](http://blog.brabadu.com/2011/04/enhancing-git-commit-message-template.html)

You can grab the whole commit message by using `%b` and `%B`, but could run into issues with multiline commits.  Might be able to get fancy with `%-b` and `%-B`, or just read more in the [Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) (scroll to format)

Comment: Remember to delete the temp file, and add a `\n` at the end of the `printf` (it doesn't include a newline like `echo` does.

Comment: @BrianCampbell Added the new lines after the message. Hopefully got the clean up right too.

Comment: `trap "rm -f $TEMP" exit` should do it (generally put after the line creating the temp file so that if later lines exit it will still run).

Comment: Oh, yeah, and for `printf`, you should generally use a format string and provide `$MSG` as a separate variable, so it doesn't get interpreted as a format string. `printf "\n\n# Last Commit: %s \n\n" "$MSG"`. You wouldn't want a commit message of "Replace \n with \r\n for Windows compatibility" to cause those actual newlines to show up in your template.

Comment: Thanks @BrianCampbell.  I'm still new to the shell scripting, don't do it much.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. One last thing is that as you say, this only works for one-line commit messages, but you are using `%B` to get the whole commit message. You can use `%s` to just get the subject, or first line of the commit message, so it won't break on multi-line commit messages.

Comment: Updated to use `%s` and added footnote about other format options.

Comment: Note that I had to save the file as `prepare-commit-msg` for it to work.

Comment: very cool! but this script corrupts fixup automatic commit messages too.